# What's the best way to add USB support to a project

Tags: usb

It just so happened that I need to add a usb communication for my next project that I am working on.What's the best/cheapest way to do this.

Should I be using a microcontroller with USB support like maybe the ATMEGA32U2 or use a ftdi chip,or maybe something else.

I have never really worked with USB before,so any help would be nice.

Comment: "Best" == cheapest, fastest, least components, least code, least complex? What do you want to do over USB? A serial to USB bridge might be sufficient.

Comment: Why do you need to add USB communication? What is its purpose? What is your general application? USB support isn't just a simple yes/no checkbox.

Comment: @RogerRowland Okay maybe I should have been a little more descriptive.I basically want a circuit that connects to my computer so that I am able to open/close doors using my computer.And as I said I have little to no experience with any USB related projects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am going to assume "best" way is easiest.

You may want to check first if you can find a library with proper USB APIs for a specific MCU or for a chip. Many vendors provide software support. Simply put, do not go for one unless they offer API support. Its a painfull process to build the protocol from scratch and it shouldn't be. Easiest would be if you have USB built into chip. Its cheap and comparatively easy to program than having to accommodate two ICS, increasing cost, effort in soldering etc.

Comment: Thanks,I'll see if I can find a appropriate MCU or not.

Comment: all major semiconductor companies provide USB libraries. Make sure you ask for example code for your MCU. Then its easy for you to edit the code to develop what you want. That is a good starting point. Search for top semiconductor manufacturers. They all have ok support

Answer (score 3):

It depends on your volume. If you're making thousands of your board, then it's probably best to find a chip you like, lay out your PCB for it, and use that. My personal favourite is NXP's LPC11U-series. They're nice because they're modern ARM Cortex cores, have a built-in bootloader that emulates USB storage. So when you enable the bootloader and plug in your device, the computer it's plugged into will show it as a USB drive. You can then copy/paste in a new firmware binary there and upgrade it like that. It makes it super easy for you and your end-users to upgrade firmware.
Writing firmware for them is also very nice and easy thanks to the mbed project which supports those chips.

If you're doing something low-volume, then use modules, the cheapest you can find. Go to Aliexpress.com or Alibaba and look for Arduino clones. The clones of the Arduino Nano are great and they have ATmega32u4-based ones too. These boards are ridiculously cheap, going from $2.5 USD to $5.50. In low volumes, a USB chip, plus passives, plus connector, will run you more than that, so it's a crazy good deal.

Avoid FTDI at all costs. They're a rotten company and have screwed over people pretty bad by bricking clones of their chips on purpose. You can read about that here: http://arstechnica.com/information-technology/2014/10/ftdis-anti-counterfeiting-efforts-sit-between-a-rock-and-a-hard-place/
While it may seem like breaking cloned devices is OK, a lot of people paid FTDI-prices thinking they got genuine chips but were actually counterfeit. The supply chains for these are complex enough, and the clones good enough, that it's very difficult for manufacturers to tell them apart.

Comment: Okay cool.I'm not interested in high volume at the moment,maybe 10 of quantity for now.So I'll be hopefully using an arduino nano.Thanks for your advice.And I'll definitely be avoiding FTDI.

Answer (score 1):

To a large extent, it depends on if your concern is development ease or unit cost.

Using a USB-enabled microcontroller as the heart of your project tends to be the cheapest (or at least lowest parts count) solution, and has the greatest flexibility in how the USB interface is used.  For example, you can implement serial port, keyboard or mouse, audio device, storage device, or entirely custom types of communication schemes.  However, there is a downside in that servicing the USB port regularly adds complexity to your firmware.  Further, if you are depending on USB to obtain status or debug message from your firmware, various common types of misoperation (leaving interrupts disabled, code runaways, hitting a breakpoint, etc) can break the USB interface in situations where a simpler UART output channel would probably keep working.  Resetting your microcontroller can also be problematic, as it may require re-enumeration by the host.

Using a distinct USB-serial converter, be it a fixed function chip (FTDI, SiLabs, CH340, etc), or a separate micro providing only bridge functionality (ATmega16u2 as on an Arduino Uno, etc) has a key advantage in keeping the moderately time-critical servicing of the USB bus distinct from your firmware.  Normally, your USB interface chip will keep happily running and proxying serial data, even as your main microcontroller firmware may crash, be restarted, reprogrammed, paused with a breakpoint debugger, etc - all operations which tend to break a USB interface and require re-enumeration to the host.  That can be a huge timesaver during development, but is less important as a project matures.

FWIW, when I build something intended to utilize an on-chip USB interface, I habitually break out the signals of a UART to a header or solderable vias, so that I can use an external logic-level USB-serial for debug output early in the development cycle.